# Инициализация слайдера

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slider

Как при ajax подгрузке товаров, сделать заново инициализацию слайдов?
Сделал так, но при клике на след происходить переинициализация, а если кликнуть на предыдущую, то работает норм

решил так

```
       $('body').on('click','.showButton', function(){
            setTimeout(function () {
            swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
                  slidesPerView: 1,
                  slidesPerGroup: 1,
                  navigation: {
                    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
                    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
                  }
            });
        }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью callback после подгрузки товара фунцией `initialSlide()` или `swiper.init()`

```
swiper.initialSlide(slideIndex)
swiper.init()
```

В  [документации](https://idangero.us/swiper/api/#initialize) всё есть

Comment: а на какое событие поставить?

Comment: @Ssasha нужен код, как я подскажу ?) повесь на load

Comment: в вопросе добавил код если кликаем на показать еще

Comment: сайт вот этот https://kristroom.ru/katalog

Comment: @Ssasha инициализация слайдера происходит до создания новых слайдеров в DOM, необходимо его инициализировать после появления на странице. Нашел тут решение, похожая проблема была https://muut.com/i/swiper/general:init-swiper-after-ajax_1

Comment: обновил в ответе реализацию, но все ровно не листает

Comment: почему-то не видит все ровно

Comment: @Ssasha не mySwiper, а свою переменную в который лежит объект инициализируй